# Does an event gets executed twice if callback was assigned twice to the object?

Tags: c#, java

I have a code that attaches an event to a form.

```
this.form.Resize += new EventHandler(form_Resize);
```

As you see this is done by `+=`.
If the above code is executed twice or multiple times,

like this:

```
this.form.Resize += new EventHandler(form_Resize);
this.form.Resize += new EventHandler(form_Resize);
this.form.Resize += new EventHandler(form_Resize);
this.form.Resize += new EventHandler(form_Resize);
this.form.Resize += new EventHandler(form_Resize);
```

Is the callback method attached multiple times?

How many times will be called the method
`form_Resize` ?

Does an event gets executed multiple times if it's callback method was assigned multiple times to the same object?

Comment: No, I don't. I though optimizer will see this forehead and won't attach multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event handler will get called once for each time it is attached. (C#)

To guard against double attachment you can use this pattern:

```
this.form.Resize -= new EventHandler(form_Resize); 
this.form.Resize += new EventHandler(form_Resize);
```

The first statement will not throw an error if there are no handlers attached and will remove an existing handler.

Comment: In your example, you're creating two _different instances_ of the `EventHandler`, so it wouldn't prevent you from multiple invocations. You'd have to create the `EventHandler` once and store it in a local variable to make this work...

Comment: That is incorrect.  `System.Delegate` overrides `Equals`; to the event handler removal code, those two objects are equal even though they're two different instances, and the event handler gets removed if it was already present.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99bthb1z.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

It will in C# - I don't know about Java.  You are adding multiple delegates to the same method and each one will get called in turn.

Here is a quick example that proves it:

```
using System;

class Example
{
    static event Action Bar;

    static void Main()
    {
        Bar += Foo;
        Bar += Foo;

        Bar();
    }

    static void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: How to figure out if a delegate has been already attached to the event, so to not attach again?

Comment: You will need to call `GetInvocationList` on the event and check to see if the delegate has already been added. This will only work inside the type that owns the delegate so if you don't own the source of the type that exposes the delegate you won't be able to do this.

Comment: @Pentium10: As Doug mentioned you can use -= before += to remove your existing event handler, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates are allowed in invocation list, so yes, the method will be executed several times. In C# at least.